# What is the most efficient way to change the values of columns, and see if a row has all the same values if the array is infinitely large?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was wondering how to approach a specific type of algorithm or what data structure to use. The algorithm is essentially, if given an infinitely large two dimensional array (in this case, lets say a 100,000 by 100,000 array), what would be the most EFFICIENT way to go through every column and change values, AND also be able to see if a row has all the same elements(go through all the rows)

EDIT: I meant large fixed dimensions, not infinitely large. Essentially all the time elements in the array are 1s and 0s. Also when running my algorithm using a simple 2d array I got a time limit exceeded error, which I am sure was caused by traversing through every single row. So I just need a faster way to change values in columns. But more importantly see which rows have matching elements.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is quite ambiguous which makes it hard to answer. You mention an 'infinitely large' array but then provide specific dimensions as an example. Do you really mean 'arbitrarily large'? Infinitely large implies that both rows and columns could be added without end. Arbitrarily large means that the size is fixed but could be anything. This has a large bearing on the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Is the size limited by physical memory? If not then the algorithm would need to have a way of persisting data temporarily as it progresses which is quite complicated to do efficiently. That's why we have databases!

Answer (score 0):

Several answers are possible. You need to give detail of purpose. Because if creation is not important for your system, if insertion is not too important for you than you can use

- B/B+ Tree

Also if there is any key in these rows to order them and i assume again insertion is not important you can also use

- Heap

It is more easy to implement. This list can be longer. First you need is decide what is more important for you? Search cost, Insert cost etc.. Because there is no any perfect data structure.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question exactly as it is written, the most **efficient** data structure for this would be a continguous 1 dimensional array with the index generated using a simple `row * rowLength + column` calculation. Going through each column and changing values or checking values would be a very fast index operation.

However that obviously puts limits on the size of your array. Without further information about the meaning of 'infinite' in your question (specifically whether the sizes can change) then it's hard to give further guidance.

Note that using your example of a 100k x 100k array, if the values were 4 bytes then you'd need around 40 Gb for the array. That might be a challenge to hold in RAM which implies persistent storage and swapping during the operation. Needless to say that's not simple.